# How to add unhandled exceptions quick fix to method in Visual Studio Code Java extension editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-java

Eclipse has an option to add unhandled exception to current try/catch or add it to the method "throws" clause. Is there a way to replicate this funcionality in Visual Studio Code Java plugin?